# Run a java program through java code

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, system-calls, java-communication-api

I am working in Linux/Ubuntu. I want to run a process in through my java code, which looks like below

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/lib/flume-ng/bin/flume-ng", 
                                       "agent", 
                                       "-f", 
                                       "/home/c4/Flume/New/ClientAgent.config",
                                       "-n", 
                                       "clientAgent");
    pb.start();
```

But i get `unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown pb.start();` as error output. Please tell me how i can run my process. Thanks.

Comment: Please read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: Since start method throws an IOException, you need to either put them in try catch block or add throws IOException  to get rid of the problem

Answer (score 4):

It's telling you the `start()` method *could* throw an Exception, and [you have to deal with it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). You can either:

1. catch it and log it or otherwise handle it, or
2. declare your method as possibly throwing this exception, and let a method higher up the stack handle it (using these two options)

The `Exception` object is *checked*, which means the compiler is concerned with it, and you need to be too (however much of a pain that is). Other exceptions are *unchecked*, and this means you don't have to worry. The compiler won't worry either (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError` - be aware that I'm mixing some exception terminology here, since it's a little convoluted).

Answer (score 2):

Since, `IOException` is a **checked** exception you need to either `catch` it

```
try {
    pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or `throw` it with the enclosing method declared to do so.

```
public void yourMethod() throws IOException {
```